# Javascript removeChild array

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, removechild

this looks simple enough but I just can't get it to work. I could add DOM elements but I just can't remove them when using an array.

```
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
count = 0;
function addInput() {
  if (fields != 10) {
      var htmlText =  "<input type='search' value='' name='field[]' />";
      var remButton = "<input type='button' value='del' onclick='remove()' />";
      var newElement = document.createElement('div');

      newElement.id = 'SomeID'+fields; 
      newElement.innerHTML = htmlText + remButton + newElement.id;

      var fieldsArea = document.getElementById('text');
      fieldsArea.appendChild(newElement);

      fields += 1;
  } else {
     ...
  }
count++;
}

// NEED HELP FROM HERE PLEASE
// You don't need to Loop, just get the button's id and remove that entire 'SomeID'


function remove() {
  fieldsArea = document.getElementById('text');


  fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID1);   <-----------------------THIS WORKS!
  fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID+count); <------------------THIS JUST WOULDN'T

  count--;
}
</script>
```

In the remove function, writing SomeID1 works and delete the first added element but when I try to use a 'count', I just can't delete my 'elements'.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a reference to the element first. Currently you are passing an undefined variable `SomeID` to the function.

E.g.:

```
var element = document.getElementById('SomeID' + fields);
// or starting by zero: var element = document.getElementById('SomeID0');
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

If you want to remove the `div` for which the button was clicked, you have to pass a reference to the corresponding `div` to the `remove` function.

```
'<input type="button" value="del" onclick="remove(this.parentNode)" />';
```

`this` will refer to the button and as it is a child of the `div`, `this.parentNode` refers to that `div`.

You also have to change your function to accept the element that should be removed:

```
function remove(element) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);   
  count--;
}
```

You probably also have to update `fields`, but I'm not sure how your code is supposed to work.

---

If you want to remove all of them you have to loop:

```
for(;fields--;) {
   var element = document.getElementById('SomeID' + fields);
   element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Also have a look at the [documentation of `removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling - I'm trying it out now :)

Comment: @lixcab: You had some errors in your HTML (like duplicated closing body tags). I corrected your fiddle and made the delete buttons work. Have a look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/GnwpM/1/ Also you don't need the `count` variable. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again! reviewing now! :)

Comment: I am an idiot playing with Javascript and you, sir, are not. :) Thank you!

Comment: @lixcab: You're welcome :) Practice, practice, practice ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The `removeChild` needs a node (DOM element) as parameter. In this case

```
fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID+count);
```

you could for example pass the node this way

```
fieldsArea.removeChild(document.getElementById('SomeID'+count));
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried them both but I just can't get it to work. fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID1) sure works but  fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID+count) wouldn't (maybe because it's a string and not a DOM) There has to be something else I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @lixcab: `fieldsArea.removeChild(SomeID1)` cannot work unless `SomeID1` is a variable containing a DOM element.

Comment: Both? just the second code snippet should work (fieldsArea.removeChild(document.getElementById('SomeID'+count)) :D ..btw, you could make an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can easily check what's wrong with your code ;)